# High memory utilization in PDFTron PDF 2 XOD conversion

Tags: java, pdf, pdftron

We are using `PdfTron` to convert a `PDF` to `XOD` so that it can be viewed in XPS viewer. `PDFTron` is deployed on `PCF` and used as a service.

Encountered a case when a simple scanned pdf file(5mb), on which OCR is already performed, is taking a huge amount of RAM(5.5GB) while converting it to XOD.
We are using following configuration to convert it in java:

```
    XODOutputOptions options = new XODOutputOptions();
    options.setDPI(600);        
    options.setPreferJPG(true);
    options.setFlattenContent(0);
    options.setRenderPages(true);
```

Is there any setting or memory management technique to workaround this issue?

Comment: Can you post a link to the file here, or send to support at pdftron.com. Since the issue is file specific we would need access to the file.

Comment: Actually it is a client's file, so cannot share

Comment: What version of PDFNet are you using? PDFNet.getVersion() at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the PDF contains a single image per page, and the image might be using JBIG2 compression, especially if it is mono/gray color.

Also you have the DPI fairly high, so if the physical dimensions of the page are large (CAD drawings are often over 30" wide/high), than this can require very large images to be in memory during conversion.

For example, if the PDF pages are 30"x30" then at 600DPI there could momentarly be a single 324MP image in memory.

You can verify by dropping SetDPI to something smaller, like 96, to verify that this is what is happening.

Comment: Is there any way through which we can pass dpi for big and small size pages in a pdf, i.e. for A4 size, use 600 and for bigger, use 300? I am asking this because when dpi decreased to 150, I have seen potential decrease in quality of converted XODs in terms of visibility of text in that particular page.

Comment: I would recommend trying the latest version of PDFNet to generate your XOD files. Please confirm which version you are using. See my comment to your original question on how to get the version.

Comment: Thanks @ryan, with the latest version of Pdftron, it gave no such problem. I was using 6.6 and updated to 6.7

Comment: A little doubt @ryan, do Convert.toXod methods processed and stores the converted file in memory or it persists over disk?